# Writing CloudWatch log into S3 bucket and we are getting LimitExceededException Resource limit exceeded from AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, devops

```
ERROR LimitExceededException: Resource limit exceeded.
at Request.extractError (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/protocol/json.js:52:27)
at Request.callListeners (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:106:20)
at Request.emit (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:78:10)
at Request.emit (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:688:14)
at Request.transition (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)
at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)
at /var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10
at Request.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)[1]
at Request.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:690:12)
at Request.callListeners (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:116:18) {
code: 'LimitExceededException',
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/194Zf.png)

Comment: This might be caused by throttling. You can send 3,500 PUT/COPY/POST/DELETE or 5,500 GET/HEAD requests per second per prefix in an Amazon S3 bucket". Try not to write all the logs into the same prefix.

Comment: Show the code from your Lambda. also, is this the *complete* stack trace? It's missing any references to the AWS API that's being invoked, as well as any reference to your code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As this [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatchLogs/latest/APIReference/API_CreateExportTask.html) say, Each account can only have one active (RUNNING or PENDING) export task at a time. So the most plausible explanation is that you already have a writing process running or pending.